# How to disable the line under tool strip in winform c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

[image]

this line ?

Comment: How did you get the background white?  That's not standard.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's a bug in the "system" renderer, details in [this bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=92862).

Microsoft's response gives a very easy workaround:

1) Create a subclass of `ToolStripSystemRenderer`, overriding `OnRenderToolStripBorder` and making it a no-op:

```
public class MySR : ToolStripSystemRenderer
{
    public MySR() { }

    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
    }
}
```

2) Use that renderer for your toolstrip. The renderer must be assigned *after* any assignment to the toolstrip's RenderMode property or it will be overwritten with a reference to a System.Windows.Forms renderer.

```
toolStrip3.Renderer = new MySR();
```

Comment: +1, but I've edited the answer to actually *include* the answer rather than only pointing to it. StackOverflow should stand alone, external links can rot. They make a good adjunct, but the main content should be on SO itself.

Comment: Why is this shutting down my application?

Answer (score 12):

You might want to add type check to avoid missing border on `ToolStripDropDownMenu`/etc. (since inherited from `ToolStrip`, it starts same custom renderer usage automatically):

```
protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ToolStrip.GetType() == typeof(ToolStrip))
    { 
        // skip render border
    }
    else
    {
        // do render border
        base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
    }
}
```

Missed `ToolStripDropDownMenu` border is not so noticable while using `ToolStripSystemRenderer` but become real eyesore with `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`.

Also, setting `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripManager.Renderer = new MySR();` could be usefull if you want all `ToolStrip` instances appwide to use `MySR` by default.

Answer (score 2):

This class is more complete than other!

```
public class ToolStripRender : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public ToolStripRender() : base() { }

    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.ToolStrip is ToolStrip))
            base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution to hide only toolstrip border and not dropdownmenu border does not work.

This is what does the trick:

```
protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (!(e.ToolStrip is ToolStrip)) base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e); - does not work!
        if (e.ConnectedArea.Width != 0) base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
    }
```