# How to avoid 3 pixel gap on left of ToolStrip in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, margin, padding, toolstrip

I'm using Windows 7 and Winforms/C#.

When I add a toolstrip to a toolstrip container, I get 3 pixels of space to the left of the toolstrip. Even if I set the location to 0,0, it resets it back to 3,0. Here is a picture to demonstrate this:

[image]

How can I avoid this? I've set the padding and the margin of the ToolStripContainer to 0,  and experimented with different RenderModes, but nothing seems to help. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try changing the toolstrip items (e.g there appears to be a spacer on there), see if changing the padding / margins to 0 for that effect it...

Comment: No spacer item (or any other item), I just set the GripMargin to 10, 2, 2, 2 so it's easier to drag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.RowMargin = new Padding(0);
}
```

Just have to set the `RowMargin` property of the ToolStripPanels within the `ToolStripContainer`. It is not available in the designer so it needs to be set in code as seen above. Apparently by default, the `Left` property of that `RowMargin` is set to 3. That is why the location was not changing when you set it to 0.

Result:

[image: ToolStripContainer with RowMargin of 0]

EDIT: It seems I've sparked my own curiosity. Now I'm trying to see if I can get rid of the 2 pixel gap at the bottom. That one seems a lot harder to track down so far.

EDIT 2: Ok I figured it out. It was being done by the the `ToolStrip`'s Renderer. In this example, I was using `System` as the `RenderMode`, so I added a new class in the project that inherits from `ToolStripSystemRenderer` and overrode the `OnRenderToolStripBorder` method and commented out the call to the base method.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class MyToolStripSystemRenderer : ToolStripSystemRenderer
    {
        protected override void  OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            //base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added another line in the form's constructor to assign the custom renderer.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.toolStrip1.Renderer = new MyToolStripSystemRenderer();
    this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.RowMargin = new Padding(0);
}
```

Result:
[image: ToolStrip panel with RowMargin of 0 and no 2 pixel border]

Edit 3: So I found out today this is a known bug with `ToolStripSystemRenderer`. I suppose I didn't find it because I was initially thinking it had something to do with the `ToolStripContainer`. Anyway, for those who it helps, here's a SO question regarding the "border" of the toolstrip. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2060360/2056131

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I've just opened up a 50 point bounty for this which you might be interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120432/moving-toolstrip-just-a-little-too-far-left-will-create-a-new-row-if-another-too

Comment: @DanW yes I've seen that question and have been playing with it for a few days when I could find time. It is not a problem that can be solved cleanly. I've posted a solution (surprisingly it is the shortest of the ways I tried and probably the least buggy too), I hope it works for you.